# SeaDragon Mouse Clicks navigation

Tags: asp.net, seadragon

I'm trying to build a page in which contains images and while clicking images i want it to navigate to next page.

I've had a look at Seadragon but as far as I can see it is not possible.

Can anyone propose a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your description exactly what you're trying to do, but I imagine it's possible with the latest version of OpenSeadragon:

http://openseadragon.github.io/

Take a look at these possibilities:

http://openseadragon.github.io/examples/tilesource-sequence/
http://openseadragon.github.io/examples/ui-reference-strip/

... Or you could add a custom click handler to do what you want.